# How to check if my application is installed on client machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, client, activex

I have an asp.net page that contain a link which I need to do the following:

When user click, it check if my desktop application is installed on this client machine or not, if yes then run it, else ask user to download it.

How can I do this function?

Comment: So, you want to execute custom code that can freely access the file system on a click of a link in the browser? I *really* hope something like that is not possible.

Comment: Have you considered deploying your desktop app using ClickOnce? This will install if not already present and run it. It will also upgrade it if there is a newer version on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless you have a trusted plugin running on the web page that has access to the file system (Silverlight or Java, for example).  This would typically be considered a pretty big security risk.

Answer (score 0):

If your client app install activex you can try something like this

```
function tryCreateXObject(name){
        try{
            return new ActiveXObject(name);
        }
        catch(err){
            return undefined;
        }
};
```

but its not ideal solution

Comment: Sanja Melnichuk:: what's you mean by client app install activex ? and how can i do ?

Comment: @Space Cracker Your add tag activex and i think that your app install some activex